# Transparent QGraphicsItemGroup as a whole

Tags: qt, transparency, qgraphicsitem

I have a QGraphicsScene with 2 "layer":
- a background image
- some polygons over it (a map), that have overlapping parts

I put all my polygons in a QGraphicsItemGroup and it works well, but now I would like to change the transparency of my polygon layer as a whole. My problem is that by changing the opacity of the QGraphicsItemGroup it changes the opacity of each child polygon, so that I see the hidden parts of polygons.

An image will explain it better. This is what I have without transparency:

[image: Opaque polygons]

This is what I have with transparency, notice the white or red dots at the intersections:

[image: Ugly transparent polygons]

I tried playing with QgraphicItem flags without success.

I can not create an image then display it as overlay because I have different tooltips for each polygon. Or is there a way to fake the shapes somehow ?

I was thinking about setting the transparency in the paint method of my QGraphicsItemGroup after drawing the polygons, but I don't know where to look at.

I use qt 4.8 with python (pyside).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research in the Qt documentation, I found [QGraphicsOpacityEffect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsopacityeffect.html) which perfectly fit my needs. I only have to apply it to the QGraphicsItemGroup and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding separate polygons to a QGraphicsItemGroup which are overlapping, use a [QPainterPath](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainterpath.html).

This will also speed up the rendering by only having to draw one painter path object, rather than all the separate items in the group.

> *I can not create an image then display it as overlay because I have different tooltips for each polygon. Or is there a way to fake the shapes somehow ?*

I assume you're working out which polygon the mouse is over and then displaying the relevant tool tip, in which case, you could keep a separate set of polygons in the scene that are hidden and use this to work out which polygon the mouse is over.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would have to rewrite lots of my code while QGraphicsOpacityEffect is just a few lines added. Another problem with a custom QPainterPath is that I would have to manage the z-value of my items by hand (both for painting and tooltips)